# Pyspark agregate sort and score

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say a table A:

```
Year          product     rating
07/02/2018    A           good
07/02/2017    B           good
07/02/2016    A           bad
07/02/2015    C           medium
07/02/2016    C           bad
```

In a first phase, I wish to obtain the following table:

```
product  year          score 
A        07/02/2018     1
A        07/02/2016     3
B        07/02/2017     1
C        07/02/2016     3
C        07/02/2015     2
```

The second phase:

```
product  year          score for oldest date 
A        07/02/2016     3
B        07/02/2017     1
C        07/02/2015     2
```

what is the shortest way to do this ? ( ranking, change scores from strings to numbers, aggeregate). Can I do all these steps in one shot ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to map the column to an Integer value.
You can use Map -

```
diz = {k:str(v) for k,v in zip(rating.keys(),rating.values())}
```

check this [replace values of one column in a spark df by dictionary key-values (pyspark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776283/replace-values-of-one-column-in-a-spark-df-by-dictionary-key-values-pyspark?rq=1)

Then use sorting/aggregation to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make Abhishek solution more concrete, suppose you have dataframe given above.

**First phase**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.types import * 

# replace rating to score
df2 = df.na.replace({'good': '2', 'bad': '0', 'medium': '1'}, value=1, subset='rating')
# cast rating score to integer
df2 = df2.select('date', 'product', fn.col('rating').cast(IntegerType()).alias('score'))
# sorting by product and score
df2.sort(fn.col('product'), fn.desc('score')).show()
```

You can also just use `fn.col('score')` if you want to sort ascending instead.

**Second phase**

Pretty much the same as in first one. However, you have to apply `unix_timestamp` to parse date and sort by product and parsed date.

```
df2 = df.na.replace({'good': '2', 'bad': '0', 'medium': '1'}, value=1, subset='rating')
df2 = df2.select('date', 'product', 
                 fn.col('rating').cast(IntegerType()).alias('score'), 
                 fn.unix_timestamp('date', format='MM/dd/yyyy').alias('date_dt'))
df2 = df2.sort(fn.col('product'), fn.asc('date_dt'))
```

Then `groupby` product and grab first `date` and `score`

```
df2.groupby(fn.col('product')).agg(fn.first(fn.col('date')), fn.first(fn.col('score'))).show()

>>
+-------+------------------+-------------------+
|product|first(date, false)|first(score, false)|
+-------+------------------+-------------------+
|      B|        07/02/2017|                  2|
|      C|        07/02/2015|                  1|
|      A|        07/02/2016|                  0|
+-------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to :

Comment: @Lizou, you want to...?

Comment: What if I want to realize the second phase ( please refer to the main question) Thank you in advance

Comment: @Lizou, I updated the solution. Let me know if it works properly!