# updating pyspark dataframe column based on nested dictionary

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, dataframe, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe of ~70 mil rows with 3 columns ['id','date','val']
and a nested dictionary in the form of

```
dict = {
    'A' = {
        '2018-09-31' = val1,
        '2018-10-01' = val2
    }
}
```

A is the ID column and there is another column for the dates.
I am trying to update val which is in another column based on this nested
dictionary accessible by dict['A']['2018-09-31'] for example.
Also, the update will only be if A is contained in a list, indexList.

I have looked at and tried the methods from below:

1. [Updating a dataframe column in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109916/updating-a-dataframe-column-in-spark)
2. [replace values of one column in a spark df by dictionary key-values (pyspark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776283/replace-values-of-one-column-in-a-spark-df-by-dictionary-key-values-pyspark)
3. [Pyspark: Replacing value in a column by searching a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976237/pyspark-replacing-value-in-a-column-by-searching-a-dictionary)

Something like below wouldn't work

```
update_func = (F.when(F.col('id').isin(indexList), mydict[F.col('id')][F.col('date')]).otherwise(F.col('val')))
df = df.withColumn('new_val, update_func)
```

The error message I get is unhashable type: 'Column'

update: I avoided the problem by creating a new string key column combining the two columns used as keys

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? @tkim