# Modify/Update pyspark colum values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I would like to modify the column values as below.
If the column value is "BALL-KG", I want to modify that value to "BALL" otherwise, teh column values remains the same
Input Columns:

```
Name      Product
John      PIPE
Hema      BALL-KG
Basha     BALL-KG
Hari      BALL
Bijju     BAG
```

Output:

```
Name      Product
John      PIPE
Hema      BALL
Basha     BALL
Hari      BALL
Bijju     BAG
```

Thanks.

Comment: Related to [Pyspark replace strings in Spark dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038014/pyspark-replace-strings-in-spark-dataframe-column) and [replace values of one column in a spark df by dictionary key-values (pyspark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776283/replace-values-of-one-column-in-a-spark-df-by-dictionary-key-values-pyspark)

Comment: a simple when/otherwise clause would suffice, i think this question lacks research but here u go `df.withColumn("Product", F.when(F.col("Product")=="BALL-KG",F.lit("BALL")).otherwise(F.col("Product")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, assuming `df` is your input data frame:

```py
Import PySpark.sql.functions as F

df=df.select(F.col("Name"), F.when(F.col("Product")==F.lit("BALL-KG"), F.lit("BALL")).otherwise(F.col("Product")).alias("Product"))
```

```
F.when(<condition>, <option_if_met>).otherwise (<if_not_met>)
```

it's `if` `else` syntax in PySpark

Comment: Honestly - I never used it for `lit`, I was always importing it separately, but you're right - with this writing I do need it. Thanks!